# How to convert Pandas Timestamp into nano since Epoch?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pandas, epoch

What is the most efficient way to convert Pandas Timestamp into nano since Epoch?

```
import pandas as pd
ns = 1470924597871000000   
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(ns, unit="ns")
```

Then how to

```
timestamp => 1470924597871000000  ns???
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me it works nice with parameter `unit` but surprisingly without parameter too:

```
import pandas as pd
ns = 1470924597871000000  

timestamp1 = pd.to_datetime(ns)
print (timestamp1)
2016-08-11 14:09:57.871000

timestamp = pd.to_datetime(ns, unit='ns')
print (timestamp)
2016-08-11 14:09:57.871000
```

And if need convert from Timestamp to epoch:

```
print (timestamp.value)
1470924597871000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it via its value:

```
import pandas as pd
ns = 1470924597871000000   
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(ns)
timestamp.value
Out: 1470924597871000000
```

Answer (score 1):

pass `unit='ns'` to specify the unit type:

```
In [46]:
ns = 1470924597871000000   
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(ns, unit='ns')
timestamp

Out[46]:
Timestamp('2016-08-11 14:09:57.871000')
```

but this seems to work fine anyway without passing this unless you are after something else?

You can use `timestamp()` to get the timestamp value:

```
In [50]:
timestamp.timestamp()

Out[50]:
1470920997.871
```