# convert pandas Series of dtype <- 'datetime64' into dtype <- 'np.int' without iterating

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, epoch

consider the below sample `pandas DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[pd.to_datetime('2016-08-11 14:09:57.00'),pd.to_datetime('2016-08-11 15:09:57.00'),pd.to_datetime('2016-08-11 16:09:57.8700')]})
```

I can convert single instance into `np.int64` type with

```
print(df.date[0].value)
1470924597000000000
```

or convert the entire columns `iteratively` with

```
df.date.apply(lambda x: x.value)
```

How can I achieve this **without using** `iteration`? something like

```
df.date.value
```

I would also want to convert back the `np.int64` object to `pd.Timestamp` object without using iteration. I got some insights from solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898809/how-to-convert-pandas-timestamp-into-nano-since-epoch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64) but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: `df['date'].astype('int64')` ?

Comment: Did you check this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852911/how-do-i-convert-dates-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-a-date-data-type

Comment: @anky/@Jorge i was grappling with this for the whole afternoon !!. This solves my problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert from datetime to integer timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312802/pandas-convert-from-datetime-to-integer-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

as per @anky comments above, the solution was straightforward.

```
df.date.astype('int64') >> to int64 dtype
pd.to_datetime(df.date) >> from int dtype to datetime64 dtype
```